# GroovySql - retrieving list of values for named parameter to use with sql in operator

Tags: mysql, sql, groovy

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax to use to pass a list of values to the 'in' operator using GroovySql. When I pass in a comma separated list of values only the first value gets applied while the other values are ignored.

My code looks like:

```
        final String query = '''\
            SELECT
                li_ch.event_id as event_id,
                sum(CASE li_ch.line_item_type WHEN 0 THEN 1 WHEN 900 THEN (CASE li_p.line_item_type WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END) sold,
                sum(li_ch.amount) as gross
            FROM
                line_item li_ch LEFT JOIN line_item li_p on li_ch.parent_line_item_id = li_p.id,
                sale s
            WHERE
                s.id = li_ch.sale_id AND
                li_ch.event_id in (${Sql) AND
                s.sale_status_type in (:eventIds) AND
                li_ch.line_item_type in (0, 900)
            GROUP BY li_ch.event_id
        '''

    // Create new Groovy SQL instance with injected DataSource
    final Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)

    def ids = eventList.collect { "'$it'" }.join(",")
    final List<GroovyRowResult> rows = sql.rows(query, eventIds: Sql.expand(ids))
    rows
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a [pull request](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-core/commit/34b629633d608adf36d5a73034b2495a2d1cee9f) to make this easier, but for now you have to join your own attributes together:

```
def values = "'${list.join('\',\'')}'"
// or less confusingly:
// def values = list.collect { "'$it'" }.join(",")
sql.rows( "select * from table where value in (${Sql.expand(values)})" )
```

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately that didn't work. With that code the query returned no results. My query is using a named parameter to get the list of values: `li_ch.event_id in (:eventIds)` and then I pass the values to the query using the syntax you suggested: `sql.rows(query, eventIds: eventIds.collect { "'$it'" }.join(","))` If I hardcode the values in the query ``li_ch.event_id in ('1', '2')` the expected results get returned.

Comment: @user1866924 whoops...can you try that edit...you have to use `Sql.expand` or else groovy tries to be clever and escape your quotes and stuff

Comment: That gives me an `java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.sql.Sql$35` exception.

Comment: I pasted my code with your suggestions into my original question

Comment: You could try moving the `Sql.expand` into the SQL statement, but if that fails, you're going to have to put the values straight into the string as in my answer, rather than using a map parameter